# Usage of Silk in Worship

Tags: sri-vaishnava, ahimsa

Even though the Hindu religion is based Non-violence (Ahimsa), the usage of silk, is prominent in worship such as in making the dress for the Lord and also in various paraphernalia. In Srivaishnava temples, even the fans used for the Lord are made out of silk and have the marks of Shankha and Chakra and Thiruman.

The Bhagavad Gita also mentions silk in [6.11-6.12](https://www.bhagavad-gita.us/bhagavad-gita-6-11-12/):

> śucau deśe pratiṣṭhāpya
>   sthiram āsanam ātmanaḥ
>   nāty-ucchritaḿ nāti-nīcaḿ
>   cailājina-kuśottaram
>
> tatraikāgraḿ manaḥ kṛtvā
>   yata-cittendriya-kriyaḥ
>   upaviśyāsane yuñjyād
>   yogam ātma-viśuddhaye
>
> To practice yoga, one should go to a secluded place and should lay kusa grass on the ground and then cover it with a deerskin and a soft cloth. The seat should be neither too high nor too low and should be situated in a sacred place. The yogi should then sit on it very firmly and practice yoga to purify the heart by controlling his mind, senses and activities and fixing the mind on one point.

So, in such cases, why is the usage of silk encouraged, and also required for certain occasions though it results in the killing of numerous silkworms?

Comment: Dear Sarvabhouma, not completely. The part where the question is asked as to why silk is used though many silkworms die is relevant to my question. But a proper answer is not given for that question.

Comment: Questions are closed as duplicates if the same question is asked to avoid repetition of same answers. Also use @username to reply to a user on your post.

Comment: @HayagreevRam, the ideal method of silk production does not involve killing silkworms. During the time when Bhagavad Gita was sung, they did not kill the worms to get silk. Nowadays, as Kali progresses, they kill them for mass-production.

Comment: @Ram then in what way was silk obtained then?

Comment: when the pupa becomes butterfly, it leaves behind the cocoon. you have to wait until it becomes butterfly, but nowdays we don't have patience

Comment: Could you kindly post these two comments as an answer?? @ram

Comment: i already mentioned it in the other answer linked by @Sarvabhouma